# Is there a way to display a ComboBox's DisplayMember value gathered from a MySQL database into a datagridview cell?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, mysql-connector

So I am trying to create a POS system where the app fetches the inventory from a database, puts all the value into a ComboBox and uses a DataGridView for the cart. My only problem is that the DataGridView Cell doesn't display the value of DisplayMember Properly.

My fetch code looks like this, and it runs at form runtime, or when manually refreshed.

```
 Using connect As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connectStr)

            Using sda As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Item, Price FROM Storeinventory", connect)
                'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)


                'Assign DataTable as DataSource.
                cart1.DataSource = dt
                cart1.DisplayMember = "Item"
                cart1.ValueMember = "Price"

                cart1Price.Text = " " & cart1.SelectedValue
            End Using
```

And with this, the name of the Product shows up properly in the combobox.

However, when adding the value of displaymember into a datagridview, it only shows up as "Item" instead of the actual product name, i.e. "Doom" but the price value is fine.

This is my main activity window:

[image]

And this is what happens when I add it:

The Price displays fine but name doesn't.
[image]

And here's my bit of code that adds the item into the datagridview:

```
 Private Sub AddCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddCart.Click
        Dim dm As String
        Dim vm As String
        Dim qt As String
        dm = cart1.DisplayMember
        vm = cart1.SelectedValue
        qt = cart1Quantity.Text
        Row = {dm, vm, qt}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You're adding a data source to the ComboBox, but it's not clear what is the DataSource of your DataGridView. It appears it's not the same DataTable. If you want to use two different DataTables, you need a DataSet that defines a [DataRelation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations). -- If you want the ComboBox to select a Value in a DataGridViewCell, you need a ComboBoxColumn where its ComboBox is filled by the DataTable you're showing here.

Comment: So the reason why my DataGridView only displays "Item" instead of the actual product name is because the DGV doesn't know where it's coming from?

Comment: Possible to share your project UI. I can't really get what exactly that you are looking for?

Comment: `cart1Item.Text = cart1.SelectedText`?

Comment: Only blank Text appears